# How to copy/select range of cells in a sheet that are enclosed with a border?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. In each sheet I have several `tables`. Each `table` has the required data enclosed with a Thick Border Border. There are **multiple** `tables` like that in each sheet. The rest of the sheet has **no borders** at all.

How can I detect the range of cells of each such table by using VBA?

Comment: Try to create another easier pattern man. Add a row with an id or something like that. You need to restrict your search

Comment: + 1 very interesting question :) I can find a cell which has that border but for an entire range, I will have to think about it. BTW how many such "tables" are there in the worksheet? On a side note: it would be much better to use named ranges for those "Tables"

Comment: If each table is surrounded by blank space, you can test each cell to find the upper left corner and use `.currentregion` to pull the rest of the data. That would be the fastest way, but it depends on your layout.

Comment: Ok I might have a solution if there is only one such "table" per sheet

Comment: Well, the number of "Tables" varies from on worksheet to another. So there is no a set number of "Tables". Also, the 'needed/required' data is surrounded by Thick Border Box, and above the columns of each table (outside the border box) there is the table's header with text - so it is not empty all around.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout, I have multiple such tables.

Comment: Ok then one last thing. Are the tables one below the other or randomly placed?

Comment: Yes, below each other - they are the same width (# of columns) as far as I can see, in the few sheets I looked into.

Comment: Perfect :) Posting a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say your worksheet looks like this.

[image]

**Logic**:

1. We will find the top left cell which has the LEFT and TOP border
2. Next we will find the bottom right cell which has the RIGHT and BOTTOM Border
3. The logic will fail if the tables are not properly formatted or have `LEFT and TOP border` and `RIGHT and BOTTOM Border` at the wrong places.
4. This is just a demonstration. If the table has data then change `What:=""` to `What:="*"`

**Code**: I am just demonstrating on how to search for the first table using `.Find`. To find the rest of the tables you will have to use `.Find` in a loop

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TopLeftCell As Range, bottomRightCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    Set TopLeftCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=True)

    If TopLeftCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlNone
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlNone
    End With

    Set bottomRightCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=True)

    If bottomRightCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Debug.Print "The Table Range is " & ws.Range(TopLeftCell.Address, bottomRightCell.Address).Address
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**Note**:

I did this exercise because I found it exciting but in real life scenario, I will never use this approach. I would use `Named Ranges` so that it is easier to work with the ranges.

---

### EDIT

Followup from comments.

To find all the tables, use this code

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Dim bCell As String

Sub Sample()
    Dim fCell As String, lCell As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

    Set aCell = ws.Cells(1, 1)

    fCell = FindTopLeftCell
    If fCell = "" Then Exit Sub

    lCell = FindBottomRightCell
    If lCell = "" Then Exit Sub

    bCell = fCell

    Debug.Print "The Table Range is " & ws.Range(fCell, lCell).Address

    Do
        fCell = FindTopLeftCell
        If fCell = "" Then Exit Sub

        If fCell = bCell Then Exit Sub

        lCell = FindBottomRightCell
        If lCell = "" Then Exit Sub

        Debug.Print "The Table Range is " & ws.Range(fCell, lCell).Address
    Loop
End Sub

'~~> Funciton to find the top left cell
Function FindTopLeftCell() As String
    Dim TopLeftCell As Range

    FindTopLeftCell = ""

    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    Set TopLeftCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=aCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=True)

    If Not TopLeftCell Is Nothing Then FindTopLeftCell = TopLeftCell.Address
End Function

'~~> Funciton to find the bottom right cell
Function FindBottomRightCell() As String
    Dim bottomRightCell As Range

    FindBottomRightCell = ""

    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlNone
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlNone
    End With

    Set bottomRightCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=aCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=True)

    If Not bottomRightCell Is Nothing Then FindBottomRightCell = bottomRightCell.Address

    Set aCell = bottomRightCell
End Function
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Correct. You could create those when you are creating that excel file.

Comment: How will I set this in a Loop to run until the last "Table"?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: First please confirm if the above gives you the first table range :)

Comment: A very clever approach to a question which I have never seen before!

Comment: @Siddharth Rout, yes it does. But how can I implement that to return the range value in a Loop? Do I change the Sub to a Function As Range?  ( I got an error for doing so). And how to Loop through the entire sheet without repeating the same lines?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: You can use a do loop? Would you like to give it a try and if you don't succeed then I will update the post with the code?

Comment: I am having Run-time '91' error if I try to return it as a Range. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I wanted to run through the sheet, and put the value in an array and use that in another loop.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: One moment. I have the code ready to find all tables. i am just trying to improve it.